# How to return a specific type of object from List<object>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have a  `List<object>` which is a collection of various type of objects.

I am writing a helper method which will return a specific type of object. The helper method will accept type name as string parameter.

Note: I am using 3.5 framework.

Comment: Will the supplied type name match the actual type of each object, or do you want to convert the object into an instance of that type?

Comment: I think you want .OfType<T> - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.90).aspx or .Cast<T>

Comment: Are you wanting the return value of the helper method to also be strongly typed, or is simply returning the proper type of object as an `object` acceptable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to use a **string** as parameter you can't rely on `OfType<T>()` extension method. Fortunately it's easy to *emulate*:

```
public IEnumerable<object> OfType(this List<object> list, string typeName)
{
    return list.Where(x => x != null && x.GetType().Name == typeName);
}
```

As pointed out by @ChrisSinclair in the comment this solution does not manage conversions, casts and inheritance/interfaces. Casts (because of user defined conversion operators) and conversions (because of `TypeConverter`s and the `IConvertible` interface) are little bit more tricky. For simple (implicit) casts (like with inheritance and interfaces) you can use this:

```
public IEnumerable<object> OfType(this List<object> list, string typeName)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    return list.Where(x => x != null && type.IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()));
}
```

**How to perform conversions (even with CUSTOM CONVERSION OPERATORS) at run-time**

I found I needed something like the code I posted in this answer but I had to extend it a little bit, here a better implementation that takes care of custom casts and conversions.

Put everything inside a `CastExtensions` class (or update code if you don't) then declare this small `enum` for its options:

```
[Flags]
public enum CastOptions
{
    None = 0,
    ExcludeNulls = 1,
    UseConversions = 2
}
```

The *problem* is that C# in general is a statically typed language, it means that almost everything (about types) must be known at compile time (then to perform a cast you have to know type your want to cast to at compile time). This function handles *simple* cases (like derivation) and more complex ones (interfaces, custom conversion operators - casts - and conversions - when required).

```
public static IEnumerable<object> OfType(this List<object> list, 
                                         string typeName, CastOptions options)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);

    foreach (var obj in list)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
        {
            if (options.HasFlag(CastOptions.ExcludeNulls))
                continue;

            yield return obj;
        }

        var objectType = obj.GetType();

        // Derived type?
        if (type.IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
            yield return obj;

        // Should we try to convert?
        if (!options.HasFlag(CastOptions.UseConversions))
            continue;

        // Castable?
        object convertedValue = null;

        try
        {
            var method = typeof(CastExtensions)
                .GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .MakeGenericMethod(type);

            convertedValue = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { obj });
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            // No implicit/explicit conversion operators
        }

        if (convertedValue != null)
            yield return convertedValue;

        // Convertible?
        if (options.HasFlag(CastOptions.UseConversions))
        {
            try
            {
                IConvertible convertible = obj as IConvertible;
                if (convertible != null)
                    convertible.ToType(type, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Exact exception depends on the source object type
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that *conversion* may be or not equivalent to a cast, actually it depends on
the implementation and the exact types involved in the operation (that's why you
can enable or disable this *feature* through options).

This is a small helper function needed for cast at run-time:

```
private static T Cast<T>(object obj)
{
    return (T)obj;
}
```

We may emit this code at run-time (I suppose even using expressions but I didn't try) but a small helper method will generate exactly the code we need (conversion from an object to a generic known at run-time type). Note that this *cast* function doesn't work as expected for value types, for example:

```
int a = 1;
float a = Cast<float>(a); // Run-time error
```

This is because `(object)1` cannot be converted to anything else than `int` (this is true for all boxed value types). If you're using C# 4.0 you should change `object` for parameter `obj` to `dynamic` and everything will work as expected (for all types).

Comment: Anil didn't specify, but this would not take into account inheritance/interfaces. If that's fine, all the better as otherwise it gets a bit more complicated/slow. Not knocking your solution (+1), just so Anil is aware.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair you're right, it wasn't in the question so I didn't even think about it!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like that :

```
var ofTypeTypeA = myList.OfType<TypeA>();
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean way is to force the user to specify the type *as type* to avoid loose strings in your application.

Then you could use generics and just use the type you are interested in. That would also allow the caller to skip the cast when using the IEnumerable later.

So instead of this:

```
List<object> newList = GetOfType(myList, "SomeObject");
// CAST!!
SomeObject someObject = newList[0] as SomeObject;
if (someObject != null)
    // use object
```

you would just do:

```
IEnumerable<SomeObject> newList = myList.OfType<SomeObject>();
foreach (SomeObject someObject in newList){
    // no cast neccessary
```

This makes it unsensitive in the future if you should rename the class `SomeObject` (because refactoring tools would pick up on the class name instead of the string)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

```
var input = new List<object>();
input.Add(1);
input.Add("foo");
var bar = input.OfType<string>();
```

Comment: As with GeorgesD answer, this does not meet the OP's requirement of accepting the type name as a parameter.

Comment: That was not in the original question. It was most likely edited after it was created.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to cast a single object extracted from the list to a strongly-typed object. And not to cast all the list to it. Otherwise use `List<MyType>`.

So I would go with this: [How to cast to a type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4959320/505893).

Answer (score -3):

You could use the is operator (or pass the type and check for that also using is). Here is an example of using the is operator:

```
foreach (var ctl in ControlsList)
{
    if (ctl is CheckBox)
        //Do this
    else if (ctl is TextBox)
        //DoThis
}
```

And by passing the type as string in the parameter, you could do something similar to get the type to test against:

```
Type t = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
```