# Why I cannot cast derived generic type to base non-generic type (through a constrain)?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

Given this fictional example:

```
class NonGeneric
{
}

class Generic<T> : NonGeneric
    where T : NonGeneric
{
    T DoSomething()
    {
        return this; // **
    }
}
```

I'd expect it compiles: `Generic<T>` derives from `NonGeneric` and `T` must be a derived class so it satisfies its constrain.

I should be able to do this:

```
NonGeneric obj = new Generic<NonGeneric>();
```

Then there should be no problem in this instruction:

```
return this;
```

Or at least this:

```
return (T)this;
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and above example doesn't compile with error:

> Cannot convert type `NonGeneric<T>` to '`T`'

I'm doing something wrong, and I can't see it, or it's just not allowed? Why this?

---

I would avoid, if possible, any workaround like the one I describe [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13992747/1207195) (Reflection, dynamic compiled methods and so on). I would avoid `dynamic` objects too (design decision, I can't change that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
T DoSomething()
{
    return this as T;
}
```

`this` is not implicitly the same as `T` so there is a need to cast it explicitly as in the above example.

Comment: You're right, it works even if I don't understand the reason. I expected "(T)this" to work (throwing "InvalidCastException" if misused). I really can't imagine why "as" works when it should behave exactly like a plain cast.

Answer (score 7):

`this` is `NonGeneric`, `T` is `NonGeneric`, but `this` isn't necessarily `T`. They could be different subclasses, from the perspective of the compiler.

Consider the class:

```
class Red : NonGeneric
{
}
```

Then your generic class becomes:

```
class Generic<Red> : NonGeneric
    where Red : NonGeneric // constraint satisfied
{
    Red DoSomething()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

But `this` isn't `Red`, it's `Generic<Red>`, which is a different subclass of `NonGeneric` than `Red`.